# Selecting a specific node on selenium grid2 to run tests

Tags: android, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Let's say I have two android emulators attached to my selenium grid2. One is a tablet emulator and one is a mobile emulator. Currently, if I specify to run my tests on android, it appears to just choose one randomly.

If I would like to specifically select the tablet instead of the mobile emulator on the grid, is there a way to accomplish this?

EDIT: These two emulators are running on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem as well.  I found this while researching it.  You basically use the "applicationName" tag to give each node a unique ID.  Then when you specify your DesiredCapabilities object you can add that tag to the object.  There is a more thorough explanation in the link:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/PRsEBcbpNlM

Full disclosure:  I'm a selenium newbie, and am still having some other troubles setting up my grid so I haven't had a chance to test this out yet.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Happy to report that this solution is still useful 3 years later!
`capabilities.setCapability("applicationName", "test1");` when setting my DesiredCapabilities, and `-browser browserName=X,platform=Y,applicationName=test1` when starting my node. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to specify this in a docker-compose file ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set some tags that identify the two nodes. This example is used for my website testing.

Lets say I have 2 servers, one for safari and one for firefox.
I will add the first tag when starting the safari server and the second for firefox server.

```
-browser  browserName=safari,version=5.1.7,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=5
```

`-browser  browserName=firefox,version=24.0,platform=WINDOWS,maxInstances=5`

This line of code is added to specify which server I will use to run the test.

```
 var cap = new DesiredCapabilities("firefox", "24.0", new Platform(PlatformType.Windows));
```